# Map string arraylist getting key and value

Tags: java, json, groovy, hashmap

From the API response, I'm parsing the JSON

```
String myData = jsonSlurper.parseText(responseBody)
Map parsedBiblio = jsonSlurper.parseText(myData)
```

below is the output of parsedBiblio

```
{"Data": {"AppNumber": "15671037", "CustomerNumber": "81744", "Date": "08-07-2017", "Status": "Active"}, 

 "Applicants": [{"Name": "abcd Inc.", "Address": "xxx, CA (US)"}],
```

below is the code of  retrieving the `Data` key and corresponding value

```
Map<Object, Object> innerMap = parsedBiblio.get("Data")
for (Object objectName : innerMap.keySet()) {
   
       println("Key: " + objectName + " Value: "+ innerMap.get(objectName) +".");
 }
```

Let me know how I can retrieve the `Applicants` key and the corresponding values, because this is `map<string,List<string>` format, so I will declare the innermap in the below format

```
Map<String, List<String>> innerMapApplicant = parsedBiblio.get("Applicants")
```

I get this error

> Cannot cast object '[{Address=xxx, CA (US), Name=abcd Inc.}]' with class 'java.util.ArrayList' to class 'java.util.Map' due to: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: java.util.Map(groovy.json.internal.LazyMap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try retrieving Applicant as follow:

```
List<Map<String,String>> applicantList =  = parsedBiblio.get("Applicants")
```

You can fetch key and value in the map as follow :

```
  for(Map<String,String> applicantMap: applicantList)
  {
       for (Object objectName : applicantMap.keySet()) 
       {
          println("Key: " + objectName + " Value: "+ applicantMap.get(objectName) +".");
       }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I retrieve the key and values inside that map?

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand why you double parse a String

If responseBody is an string, you can write:

```
def json = jsonSlurper.parseText(responseBody)
println json.Data.Applicants.Name
println json.Data.Applicants.Address
```